# php poo establecer conexion a la base de datos

Tags: php, mysqli, poo

hola comunidad recien estoy aprendiendo la programacion orientada a objetos por motivos de escabilidad en mi aplicacion y bueno tengo este codigo para establecer conexion a la base de datos..

archivo **config.php**

```
$host="localhost";
$user="root";
$pass="";
$DBname="login";
```

y lugeo **conexion.php**

```
   require"config.php";

  class conexion{

     public function dbConnect(){


         $conexion= new mysqli($host,$user,$pass,$DBname);


         if (!$this->conexion) {


             echo"conxion width db fail: ".$this->conexion->coonect_error;
             return;
         }


     }


  }
```

me lanza el siguiente **error**...

> **Notice:** Undefined variable: host in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\pooClass_php\conexion.php on line 16
>
> **Notice:** Undefined variable: user in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\pooClass_php\conexion.php on line 16
>
> **Notice:** Undefined variable: pass in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\pooClass_php\conexion.php on line 16
>
> **Notice:** Undefined variable: DBname in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\pooClass_php\conexion.php on line 16
>
> **Notice:** Undefined variable: conn in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\pooClass_php\index.php on line 30

alguien que me pueda orientar un poco y me pueda ayudar a entender algunos conceptos? gracias!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sucede que las variabels no estan dentro de la declaracion de tu clase, aunque las tengas en un archivo externo;

> He removido el ejemplo de PDO.

Actualizo para colocar un ejemplo con mysqli con archivo separado, para ello crearemos un archivo config llamado `config.php.ini` para tener las credenciales en un archivo externo;

`config.php.ini`

```
<?php return; ?>
; credenciales
host=localhost
usuario=elusuariodeladb
clave="laclave"
dbnombre=elnombredeladb
```

Ahora nuestra clase conexion, en la misma nota que no tienes que llamar la funcion `require` o `include` ya que la funcion `parse_ini_file` se encarga de leer el archivo y asignar su valor a la propiedad credenciales;
`conexion.php`

```
class conexion {
    //Esta vez solo necesitaremos una propiedad que es de tipo array
    private $credenciales;
    protected $myconn;

    function connect() {
       $this->credenciales = parse_ini_file("config.php.ini");
        $con = mysqli_connect($this->credenciales["host"], $this->credenciales["usuario"], $this->credenciales["clave"], $this->credenciales["dbnombre"]);
        if (!$con) {
            die('no se ha podido conectar con la base de datos!');
        } else {
            $this->myconn = $con;
            echo 'exitosa';}
        return $this->myconn;
    }

    function close() {
        mysqli_close($myconn);
        echo 'conexion cerrada';
    }

}
```

Comment: podrias hacer un ejemplo con mysqli es que no uso PDO . entonces esto seria mi archivo de conexion y como podria yo acceder a la coneccion en otro archi php ?

Comment: @andygibbs he agregado el ejemplo que me pediste. Saludos.

Comment: @AlfredoPaz Disculpa fue un error del editor, esta corregido gracias!

Comment: @AlfredoPaz lo de la impresión es solo como ejemplo didáctico, todos debemos a este nivel, conocer el principio de responsabilidad única

Comment: !gracias @yo Albert tu ejemplo tanbien me funciono , podrian aclararme por fa como instanciar  la conexion a otro archivo php si no es mucha molestia

Comment: @andygibbs he modificado la respuesta para tener las credenciales en un archivo externo

Answer (score 2):

Aquí tienes un ejemplo con `mysqli`

> Considera que si estas creando un script que va a servir para hacer
>   una conexión a un servidor por ejemplo de bases de datos; entonces el
>   modificador de acceso adecuado en este caso debería ser `private` pues
>   solo estarán disponibles dentro de la clase que las posee

```
<?php

class Conexion 
{
    private $host;
    private $user;
    private $pass;
    private $dbname;

    public function __construct($host, $user, $pass, $dbname)
    {
        $this->host = $host;
        $this->user = $user;
        $this->pass = $pass;
        $this->dbname = $dbname;
    }

    public function createConecction()
    {
        $conecta = new mysqli($this->host, $this->user, $this->pass, $this->dbname);
        return ($conecta) ? 'conectado' : 'no conectado';
    }
}

$obj = new Conexion("localhost", "root", "password", "demo");
echo $obj->createConecction(); //imprimirá conectado
```

> Lo primero que hago es declarar las propiedades, posteriormente
>   declaro un método mágico `construct()`  para inicializar las
>   propiedades cuando la clase sea creada; finalmente creo un método
>   personalizado que es el que contiene el llamado a la isntancia de
>   mysqli
>
> También te hago la observación, las porpiedades que vas a utilzar las
>   debes declarar dentro del scope de la clase para que las reconozca
>   como tal cuando las deseas usar; por lo que no veo necesario que los
>   declares en otro archivo y luego lo invoques

Comment: genial! alfredo @Alfredo Paz funciono bien. ahora me puedes aclar como puedo yo instanciar la conexion cuando la necesite en otro archivo por favor. por ejemplo si tengo otro archivo con una estructura html y necesito hacer algunas consultas a mi base de datos podrias aclararme eso ?